# CSS - Optimizing constant screensize changes on the same item to increase performance

Tags: html, css, performance

A screenshot is below of the webpage that I need to optimize the screen sizes for. The horizontal bar above the navigation bar with the logos, white background and the clubs on the left is what I'm wanting to optimize the screen size CSS code for. I've only started working with html and css a few month ago.

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1GU2.png)

From 1230px the margin-left increases by 0.8px. Is there a way to increase the webpages performance with the 35+ "@media screen and (min-width: #px)" that will be needed to cater to screen min-width of 1930px or more? Or will this many not affect the pages performance at all?

```
/* Team Logos spacing for different screen sizes */
        @media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
        {
            .clubs .llul .logoli
            {
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
        }
    
        @media screen and (min-width: 1210px)
        {
            .clubs .llul .logoli
            {
                margin-left: 0.45px;
            }
        }
        
        @media screen and (min-width: 1220px)
        {
            .clubs .llul .logoli
            {
                margin-left: 0.9px;
            }
        }
    
        @media screen and (min-width: 1230px)
        {
            .clubs .llul .logoli
            {
                margin-left: 1.3px;
            }
        }
        
        @media screen and (min-width: 1250px)
        {
            .clubs .llul .logoli
            {
                margin-left: 2.1px;
            }
        }
        .
        .           
        ./* Rest of code between 1250px and 1630px */ 
        .
        .
        @media screen and (min-width: 1630px)
        {
            .clubs .llul .logoli
            {
                margin-left: 17.3px;
            }
        }
        
        @media screen and (min-width: 1650px)
        {
            .clubs .llul .logoli
            {
                margin-left: 18.1px;
            }
        }
```

I've also added a snippet of the code behind the element. The rest of the CSS for it is not shown.

```
<div class="clubs">
  <p style="display: inline;">Clubs</p>
  <ul class="llul">
     <li class="logoli"> <img class="logoT" style="" src="media/teams/smlafel.JPG" alt="fl">
        <ul class="llul">
           <li class="logoli" style="padding-left: 10px;"> <b>Africa Elite</b> </li>
           <li class="logoli"> <a href="#"> <img class="logoT" style="" src="media/teams/smlafel.JPG" alt="fl"> <b>Africa Elite</b> &nbsp; &nbsp;[Men's Premier Division] </a> </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would write javascript to do this. But maybe someone has a neat css solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't do stuff like that. You're just copying & pasting your code for `.clubs .llul .logoli` and adjusting the `margin-left` rule every `10px`. There's definitely something wrong with that from a programming point of view. This does not affect the performance (well, maybe when resizing your browser window vary fast), but your CSS file will be much messy and heavier than it has to be, so when the browser will download this file at the beginning, then loading the page, it can take a while.

The solution here is to go with this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .clubs .llul .logoli {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .clubs .llul .logoli {
    margin-left: calc((100vw - 1200px) / NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);
  }
}
```

Where `100vw` is always the window width (from CSS's point of view). So when it's bigger than `1200px`, you get the size you want to share between all your logos and divide it by some constant than can be the number of those logos, more or less than that. You can adjust it as you like.

Even more clever way to go with this is to take a look at `display: flex` and `justify-content` rules. I'll leave this link here for more infos:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flexbox-justify-content/

Hope this was useful, good luck!

Comment: Awesome, thanks that saved a ton of copy and paste. Works perfect with NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT +1 because one logo was wider than the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use svg for the logos if you have them in that format, they will scale up and down to perfection and read like code, therefore no optimisation required